# Python Client error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, sockets, arduino

I don't really know the problem but I got an error: "connection refused". I don't know what to do please help me. I'm trying to send a count when the button is pressed on android app and I'm using nanpy to connect to arduino but I got an error.

```
import socket
from nanpy import (ArduinoApi, SerialManager)


ledpin = 13
buttonpin = 12
buttonpin1 = 2
buttonpin2 = 3
buttonstate1 = 1
buttonstate2 = 1
buttonstate3 = 1

connection = SerialManager()
a = ArduinoApi(connection = connection)

a.pinMode(ledpin, a.OUTPUT)
a.pinMode(buttonpin, a.INPUT)
a.pinMode(buttonpin1, a.INPUT)
a.pinMode(buttonpin2, a.INPUT)


ADDR2 = ('192.168.1.7', 21568)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(ADDR2)

while True:

    try:
        buttonstate1 = a.digitalRead(buttonpin)
        buttonstate2 = a.digitalRead(buttonpin1)
        buttonstate3 = a.digitalRead(buttonpin2)             
        if buttonstate1:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.HIGH)
        else:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.LOW)
            add += 1
            s = str(add)
            sock.sendall(s)
            time.sleep (.5)

        if buttonstate2:                       
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.HIGH)
        else:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.LOW)
            add += 1
            s = str(add)
            sock.sendall(s)
            time.sleep (.5)
        if buttonstate3:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.HIGH)
        else:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.LOW)
            add += 1
            s = str(add)
            sock.sendall(s)
            time.sleep (.5)                                             
    finally:

        sock.close
```

## this is the error some know how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/counter.py", line 24, in <module>
    sock.connect(ADDR2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Connection refused just means nothing's listening on that IP and port. The error has nothing to do with your code and probably something to do with the address and port you're using.

Comment: thank you sir that is exactly right i opened the app and it connects but the problem is its not sending the data what would be the problem?

Comment: Now i can send but the textview in my android app only update when i close the program